# in Saml Federation, can one Idp serve as a facade for authentication against multiple "back end" IdP's

Tags: saml, adfs

**Question**

In Saml Federation, can one Idp serve as a front-end proxy for authentication against multiple "back end" IdP's

**Context**

- our multi-tenant application suports SAML for  Authentation and user provisioning
- ...and allows "one IDP" per Company (i.e. customer's organization)
- A new customer has a "main AD instance" and a "secondary AD instance" (for a newly acquired subsidiary). They don't have any short/medium term plans to merge the two AD instances
- customer wants users from both "their main company" and "their subsidiary" to appear "as one Customer" in our application

Question:

- does a means exist to allow our application to "see" one IdP, but on "the back end" have multiple Idps provide authentication.

Comment: How do you choose to which IdP's sign in page the user should be redirected for that tenant?

Comment: Yes. Good question.  I was hoping that "AD would handle that"..i.e. it would do something  like this:
-  prompt first for email address
-  route to "right server"  for the email address
- send saml response to the sp

that said, i was hoping for a 'one-stop-shopping' facade for the SP, i.e. similar to when apache/nginx/haproxy fronts a 'back end' http server.

Comment: This is out of scope of SAML and OIDC. You will have to modify the IdP. Can't you add sign-in with "secondary AD instance" option for those users?